# Liquibase column data types from generateChangeLog

Tags: oracle, db2, liquibase

I have two databases, one on DB2 and one on ORACLE. I've generated change log file via generateChangeLog command. It produced me correct xml file, but only on Oracle database. I was invoking this command on oracle database and in result I got in column data types like NUMBER(*,0) which are not valid on DB2. How can I generateChangeLog with unified data types in liquibase ?

Does some list of data types exists in liquibase ? Which are let's say versitale to all databases ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse engineering an existing DB schema to a Liquibase XML file always creates the DBMS specific datatypes. You will have to edit the generated XML file to use JDBC types.

The supported "cross-platform" types are documented in the manual:

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html

> To help make scripts database-independent, the following “generic” data types will be converted to the correct database implementation:
>
> - BOOLEAN
> - CURRENCY
> - UUID
> - CLOB
> - BLOB
> - DATE
> - DATETIME
> - TIME
> - BIGINT
>
> Also, specifying a java.sql.Types.* type will be converted to the correct type as well. If needed, precision can be included. Here are some examples:
>
> - java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP
> - java.sql.Types.VARCHAR(255)

From my experience the first list is missing `INTEGER` and `DECIMAL` which can also be used without problems (at least for Oracle and Postgres - don't have DB2 around to test it).

Comment: and what about precision in numeric values ? Is it possible to specify precision in this liquibase generic types ?

Comment: @ArturSkrzydło, as the manual states: "*If needed, precision can be included*" and in my experience `decimal` works fine. That includes e.g. `decimal(18,2)`

Comment: Are there corresponding generic data values as well? For instance if adding a BOOLEAN column (that in Oracle 19c will end up as number(1)) - in a corresponding addNotNullConstraint change's defaultNullValue field: Is there a generic value I can use for true/false?